# Regular Expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to build a list of domain names from an Enom API call. I get back a lot of information and need to locate the domain name related lines, and then join them together.

The string that comes back from Enom looks somewhat like this:

```
SLD1=domain1
TLD1=com
SLD2=domain2
TLD2=org
TLDOverride=1
SLD3=domain3
TLD4=co.uk
SLD5=domain4
TLD5=net
TLDOverride=1
```

I'd like to build a list from that which looks like this:

```
[domain1.com, domain2.org, domain3.co.uk, domain4.net]
```

To find the different domain name components I've tried the following (where "enom" is the string above) but have only been able to get the SLD and TLD matches.

```
re.findall("^.*(SLD|TLD).*$", enom, re.M)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works for you example,

```
>>> sld_list = re.findall("^.*SLD[0-9]*?=(.*?)$", enom, re.M)
>>> tld_list = re.findall("^.*TLD[0-9]*?=(.*?)$", enom, re.M)
>>> map(lambda x: x[0] + '.' + x[1], zip(sld_list, tld_list))
['domain1.com', 'domain2.org', 'domain3.co.uk', 'domain4.net']
```

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:**
 Every time I see a question asking for regular expression solution I have this bizarre urge to try and solve it without regular expressions. Most of the times it's more efficient than the use of regex, I encourage the OP to test which of the solutions is most efficient.

Here is the naive approach:

```
a = """SLD1=domain1
TLD1=com
SLD2=domain2
TLD2=org
TLDOverride=1
SLD3=domain3
TLD4=co.uk
SLD5=domain4
TLD5=net
TLDOverride=1"""

b = a.split("\n")
c = [x.split("=")[1] for x in b if x != 'TLDOverride=1']
for x in range(0,len(c),2):
    print ".".join(c[x:x+2])

>> domain1.com
>> domain2.org
>> domain3.co.uk
>> domain4.net
```

Comment: I agree!  Pythons string manipulation functions are so powerful, I feel like banging one's head against the walls with regex is often unneeded.  I rarely use `import re` anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You have a capturing group in your expression. [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re#re.findall) documentation says:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

That's why only the conent of the capturing group is returned.

try:

```
re.findall("^.*((?:SLD|TLD)\d*)=(.*)$", enom, re.M)
```

This would return a list of tuples:

```
[('SLD1', 'domain1'), ('TLD1', 'com'), ('SLD2', 'domain2'), ('TLD2', 'org'), ('SLD3', 'domain3'), ('TLD4', 'co.uk'), ('SLD5', 'domain4'), ('TLD5', 'net')]
```

Combining SLDs and TLDs is then up to you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why are you talking about regular expressions. I mean, why don't you just run a `for` loop?

A famous quote seems to be appropriate here:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.

```
domains = []
components = []
for line in enom.split('\n'):
  k,v = line.split('=')
  if k == 'TLDOverride':
    continue
  components.append(v)
  if k.startswith('TLD'):
    domains.append('.'.join(components))
    components = []
```

*P.S. I'm not sure what's this `TLDOverride` so the code just ignores it.*

Comment: I think this is the best solution, because it's O(n) algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
import re
print map('.'.join,  zip(*[iter(re.findall(r'^(?:S|T)LD\d+=(.*)$', text, re.M))]*2))
# ['domain1.com', 'domain2.org', 'domain3.co.uk', 'domain4.net']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, map -> filter -> map:

```
input = """
SLD1=domain1
TLD1=com
SLD2=domain2
TLD2=org
TLDOverride=1
SLD3=domain3
TLD4=co.uk
SLD5=domain4
TLD5=net
"""

splited = map(lambda x: x.split("="), input.split())
slds = filter(lambda x: x[1][0].startswith('SLD'), enumerate(splited))
print map(lambda x: '.'.join([x[1][1], splited[x[0] + 1][1], ]), slds)

>>> ['domain1.com', 'domain2.org', 'domain3.co.uk', 'domain4.net']
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to do what you want:

```
domains = re.findall('SLD\d+=(.+)', re.sub(r'\nTLD\d+=', '.', enom))
```

It assumes that the lines are sorted and SLD always comes before its TLD. If that can be not the case, try this slightly more verbose code without regexes:

```
d = dict(x.split('=') for x in enom.strip().splitlines())

domains = [
    d[key] + '.' + d.get('T' + key[1:], '') 
    for key in d if key.startswith('SLD')
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use multiline regex for this.  This is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740739/python-multiline-regex).

```
data = """SLD1=domain1
TLD1=com
SLD2=domain2
TLD2=org
TLDOverride=1
SLD3=domain3
TLD4=co.uk
SLD5=domain4
TLD5=net
TLDOverride=1"""

domain_seq = re.compile(r"SLD\d=(\w+)\nTLD\d=(\w+)", re.M)
for item in domain_seq.finditer(data):
    domain, tld = item.group(1), item.group(2)
    print "%s.%s" % (domain,tld)
```

Answer (score 1):

As some other answers already said, there's no need to use a regular expression here. A simple `split` and some filtering will do nicely:

```
lines = data.split("\n") #assuming data contains your input string
sld, tld = [[x.split("=")[1] for x in lines if x[:3] == t] for t in ("SLD", "TLD")]
result = [x+y for x, y in zip(sld, tld)]
```